# Exception Handling in MVC design pattern

Tags: java, exception

I am little bit confuse in best practice of exception handling in java with MVC design pattern. I am having three classes lets suppose Controller, Service and Repository. Now let me take a simple example: I need to validate login credentials in DB. If it matches we will allow user to login but if it does not match we have to give user message like "User does not exists". But in this process it might happen that we configure wrong connection parameter or there is some error in SQL, In this case it will through some exception. How should I handle exception in three different layer.  Shall I handle exception in Repository class or shall I handle it in Controller class?

Comment: That completely depends on the kind of exception. You should handle it where you can in a meaningful way. If the exception is likely to be of interest to the user, handle it in the view by displaying a pop-up. If the exception should merely be logged, you can just log it and continue. Some exceptions should never occur and you can just let your application crash on it.

Comment: You should handle it in some generic unexpected error handler, and not in any of those components. Most MVC frameworks allow doing that. An incorrect connection parameter or SQL query is a bug, and you shouldn't clutter your code with code that handles exceptions caused by bugs.